# Without params sorted descending when using python requests get method

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using python requests. I do not want the params follow a descending order.

For example.

```
In  []:  import requests
         payload = {'key2': 'value1', 'key3': ['value', 'value3']}
         r = requests.get("http://httpbin.org/get", params=payload)
         print r.url

out []:  http://httpbin.org/get?key3=value&key3=value3&key2=value1
```

What I want is `http://httpbin.org/get?key2=value1&key3=value&key3=value3`.

Comment: What do you mean by "dictionary order"? Plain Python dictionaries don't preserve the order that items were added to them.

Comment: Might be a dumb question:  why does the order matter?  URL keyword parameter order shouldn't matter.  The same applies to Python `dict`s.

Comment: Sorry, English is not good.

Comment: the order dose not matter

Comment: the order dose not matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite of there is no difference in the params order, you can always use `OrderedDict`, as follows:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
pl = OrderedDict()
pl['key2'] = 'value1'
pl['key3'] = ['value', 'value3']
r = requests.get("http://httpbin.org/get", params=pl)

print r.url  # http://httpbin.org/get?key2=value1&key3=value&key3=value3
```

Please pay attention, you should add items to the `orderedDict` **after** its init, because constructor treats params during initialization as regular dict, that doesn't preserve keys order.